# $\frac{dy}{dx} \;$ of $\; \ln\!\left(y\right)=e^{3y}\sin\!\left(x\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function, implicit-differentiation

Find $dy/dx \;\;$ if $\;\; \ln\!\left(y\right)=e^{3y}\sin\!\left(x\right)$

So I did:

$\frac{dy}{dx} \frac{1}{y} = 3e^{3y} \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \cos(x)   $

moving $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to the right hand side:

$\frac{dy}{dx} (\frac{1}{y} - 3e^{3y}) = \cos(x)$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\cos(x)}{\frac{1}{y} - 3e^{3y}}$

But [the right answer seems to be](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=implicit%20differentiation%20of%20ln%28y%29%20%3D%20e%5E%283y%29%20*%20sin%28x%29):

$\frac{dy}{dx} =  \frac{e^{3y} y \cos(x)}{1-3 e^{3 y} y sin(x)}  $

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of product is not the product of derivatives.

$\frac{dy}{dx} \frac{1}{y} = 3e^{3y} \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \sin(x) +  e^{3y} \cdot\cos(x)  $